# Slow smb mounts

Tags: pantheon-files, networking, samba

So I mapped my network drives to my machine. The server transfer speeds are fine, but it takes a long time to load the folders. like its doing a "mount -a" evry time I open a folder.

Here you can see my fstab, where i mounted the folders

```
//192.168.0.101/Werk /media/Werk cifs username=User,password=Mypas
//192.168.0.101/Media /media/Media cifs username=User,password=Mypas
//192.168.0.101/back-up /media/Back-up cifs username=User,password=Mypas
```

So normally this should work quite snappy, but it even crashes at times and takes forever to load on boot.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: So i just looked into my dmesg, and is states the following:

```
[    9.695162] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    9.695235] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    9.696084] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    9.696163] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    9.696285] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    9.696342] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[   10.445482] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   10.445658] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   10.445845] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1292 (vmnet-bridge)
[   10.445856] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
[   10.445868] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
[   10.445877] bridge-eth0: up
[   10.445921] bridge-eth0: attached
[   10.645675] userif-2: sent link down event.
[   10.645677] userif-2: sent link up event.
[   11.653835] userif-2: sent link down event.
[   11.653839] userif-2: sent link up event.
[   18.907721] /dev/vmmon[0]: HostIFReadUptimeWork: detected settimeofday: fixed uptimeBase old 18445296117582394051 new 18445296117583644640 attempts 1
```

I noticed my entire network throttles every odd minute. When I romoved the mounts, it was still there.

Edit 2:
So i just found out that it`s not just an Elementary probem, but more of a samba problem. Since the same problem reappears on other distro`s
, i will update again when I find a working solution witch alludes my for now.

Comment: Please do post your solution. I think you may find it is not just limited to samba. I find Samba and SFTP (SSH) to be equally slow at times. Though at other times it works fine.

Comment: SMB is not a particularly fast protocol - I use use ftp (to another windows machine) instead. Even dir listings of several thousand entries arrive in about one second. Doing the same over smb to the exact same machine (and interface) takes way longer. Mounting is fast and access as well. With pantheon you can even move files via ftp (not an ftp feature though), but you cannot play a video over ftp.

Answer (score 1):

I use another method to mount my SMB shares. I have a script with a line like the following for each share:

```
gvfs-mount smb://<SERVER>/<SHARE> &
```

The commands are run in the background so any delays in mounting don't hold up other things. I then created a .desktop file to autostart the script at boot.

This is particularly useful on my work laptop as the network does not come up until after I log in (security feature).

You can also unmount from within Files as with any manually mounted fs.